# Is there a way to speed up pd.read_excel() reading from .xlsm files?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

For some background, I have an Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (xlsm) which I am using to pass a few user inputted variables to Python.

Using Pandas and pd.read_excel() from xlsx files in my script is fast, even if the dataset is fairly large. However I have noticed it takes long when reading even one line from xlsm files.

Even reading one line by limiting the data to a small area like so:

```
pd.read_excel('Automation.xlsm', skiprows=6, nrows=2, usecols='B:C')
```

It can still take 20 seconds compared to 0.03 seconds from xlsx.

Is there any way to improve the speed of reading from xlsm files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. For anyone that has this problem the fix was pretty basic.

I selected all rows and columns outside of the dataset in the xlsm file and right clicked -> delete. There must have been an empty cell somewhere far out which even when specified to ignore it in pd.read_excel(), was still increasing the read time.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading it chunk at a time:

```
for chunk in pd.read_excel(filename, chunksize=10000):
    df = df.append(chunk)
```

Change chunk size dependent on your DB size

Comment: Apologies, edited my question to make it more clear. The decrease in speed occurs on a file with only 2 rows of data. So no large database.